# Angular scroll glue not work on chat app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, scroll

Im using angular glue to scroll to bottom of my chat app. But it only work on the sender site. The receiver windown didn't get the scroll to bottom.

```
 <div id="chat" scroll-glue force-glue>
        <ul id="mychat">
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Angularjs code inside chat function.

```
 Sovar myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#mychat' ) );
 myEl.append('<li><strong>' + data.user + ':</strong> ' +data.msg+'</li>');
```

Update: Use this and it work.

```
  var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#mychat' ) );
  myEl.append($compile('<li><strong>' + data.user + ':</strong> ' +data.msg+'</li>')($scope));
  $scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you append to the string, need to compile the element in order to render the html.

```
$scope.data = {"user":"user1", "msg":"this is msg"}
var target = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#mychat' ) ); 
target.append('<li><strong>'+$scope.data.user+':</strong>'+$scope.data.msg+'</li>');
$compile(target)($scope);
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$compile){
$scope.data = {"user":"user1", "msg":"this is msg"}
var target = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#mychat' ) ); 
target.append('<li><strong>'+$scope.data.user+':</strong>'+$scope.data.msg+'</li>');

$compile(target)($scope);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div id="chat" scroll-glue force-glue>
        <ul id="mychat">
      </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use this and it work. But not the same way. I edit some. Look at the update.

Comment: if you are compile after append then no need to use the apply function again